# BeautifulSoup parser not properly splitting by tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a site and then attempting to split into paragraphs. I can very clearly see by looking at the scraped text that some paragraph delimiters are not being split properly. See below for code to recreate the problem!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=111395"
response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
paras = soup.findAll('p')
# Note that in printing the below, there are still a lot of "<p>" in that paragraph :( 
print paras[614]
```

I have tried using other parsers -- similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. It happens because the page contains nested paragraphs, e.g.:

```
<p>Neurosurgeon Ben Carson. [<i>applause</i>] <p>New Jersey
```

I would use this little hack to resolve the problem:

```
html = response.content.replace('<p>', '</p><p>')  # so there will be no nested <p> tags in your soup

# then your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, `lxml` parser? I had similar issues and `lxml` solved my problems.

```
import lxml
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

Also instead of `response.content` try `response.text` to get unicode object.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately (either lxml or using response.text). Thanks for the suggestion tho!